# Auto show text when user doesn't click on picture for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code using jQuery but I am unsure what should I use for this idea. If user doesn't click on the image, the text automatically to show up after couple of seconds. Should I add animation-delay in CSS?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#picture2" ).bind( "click", function() {
        jQuery ('#txt2').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve **in detail**, as well as any specific problems you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the answer. I was going with the title question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timout that will be reset when you click the button.

In the example below, if you dont click the button for 5 seconds the text will be shown. I changed the `bind()` function to `on()` because the first is deprecated since version 3.0.

```js
//initial timeout initializer
var timer = setTimeout(handler, 5000);

//reset the timout onclick
$('#clicker').on('click', () => {
  $('#text').hide();
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(handler, 5000);
});

//hanlder function to show the text when the timeout is triggered
function handler() {
  $('#text').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clicker">Click me!</button>
<p id="text" style="display: none;">Please click me :(</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but this is not the exact solution. I've edited the answer now. The code stays as it stays, but if user doesn't click on the image, the text automatically to show up after couple of seconds.

Comment: @nikolai that is was this snippet does? If the user doesn't click the button for 5 seconds the text automatically shows up. If this is not what you want please explain whats wrong.